# A neighborhood of rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ near an irrational $\alpha$ satisfy $\frac{1}{q} < \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Consider a set of irrationals, with elements $\alpha$. The set satisfies the condition that given an $\alpha$, there exists a positive number $c$ such that for any member, $\frac{p}{q}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in lowest terms with $q > 0$, $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| > \frac{c}{q^{2}}$
(1)

A solution to a larger proof uses the facts above to claim that for any $\epsilon$ a $\delta$ exists such that whenever $|x - \alpha| < \delta$ where $x = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ (as defined above), $\frac{1}{q} < c \epsilon$.
(2)

I cannot reach this conclusion. Please help!

---

If you need the full context of this problem, let me know!

Edit: I see my error. This $c$ applies to all $\frac{p}{q}$ and does not depend on a particular "family", i.e rationals with set denominator $q$.

The more interesting question is do all irrational numbers satisfy this definition?!

Answer (score 0):

The second claim holds anyway for arbitrary irrational $\alpha$ (and arbitrarily picked $c>0$). Note that this just states that all suffciently good rational approximations have large denominators. But that is clear as there are only finitely many small denominators, and for each of those there are at most two rationals with that denominator that are candidates for being close to $\alpha$.

Comment: But if the $c$ in (2) is the $c$ satisfying (1), isn't it the case that rational numbers with different denominators, but within some neighborhood of $\alpha$, have to satisfy different conditions. If I have understood your explanation correctly, then you seem to say that sufficiently small rationals exist to guarantee that $\frac{1}{q} < c\epsilon$ where $c\epsilon$ is a fixed quantity for **all** such rationals.